# Does splitting scripts/css produce a faster execution/paint time

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, load

I know that when a browser downloads a remote script it waits until the entire file has finishes downloading before executing it(obviously).
Splitting the file into multiple remote files would increase load time but it would also allow some important code to be executed a lot sooner.

Does the Load/execution work the same for inline script?
Assuming it does then splitting inline scripts would have such a small increase in over all load time it wouldn't be noticeable and it would allow some code to execute faster results.(win win)

### Example

```
<script>
    /* 
        Critical JS Block (Any Initial visual Dom Manipulation or loading critical assets)
    */
     function loadCSS(){};  //https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS
     document.getElementbyId('textbox1').value(localStorage.textbox1);
</script>
<script>
     /* 
       Non Critical JS Block
        ui event listeners
        buttons, menus, tabs, etc
    */
</script>

<script>
    /* 
        lazy loading / pre-loading assets 
    */
</script>
</body>
```

Does this work for inline `<scripts>` and for inline `<style>` ?

```
<style>
    body{display:none;}
    /* 
        Critical CSS Block
    */ 
    body{display:block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
...
<style>

    /* 
        Non Critical CSS Block
    */ 

</style>
</body>
```

If this does work and it is a practical solution which blocks would be better as inline and which external scripts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: in theory, yes, in practice, if you're seeing rendering performance improvements when you split up your inline scripts, you most likely have some design issues.

Inline scripts/css chunks block rendering like anything else on the page (so, always place them at the bottom, after any other visual elements have loaded), and splitting them will allow for partial display until the rest of the page loads.

That said, if you're doing significant amounts of processing in your javascript, enough that your script is likely to cause user-visible delays to your page, you're much better off not making it an inline script to begin with. The easiest standard solution is to throw it into its own js file, and load it asynchronously from an inline script.